# Google Network Endpoint with Google Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer

Need help regarding the load balancer issue. The configuraton is done in such a way that, the load balancer will connect to the Network endpoing group (Zonal) and the Network endpoing group connects to the VM instance on which the application is hosted. The issue is if I accessed the page directly through the external ip address of the vm instance then page renders and if try to access the same through load balancer ip address, it return 502 Bad gateway error. Not getting whether the issue is in load balancer or in network endpoint gateway set up

Comment: Show the configuration for both. Are these long running requests? This error means that the load balancer did not like the response from the backend. Check Stackdriver for the exact error message. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring

Comment: Do you use health-checks?